# keyof for static properties of TypeScript classes

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

Given [this code sample in TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20getProp%3CT%2C%20K%20extends%20keyof%20T%3E(object%3A%20T%2C%20property%3A%20K)%3A%20T%5BK%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20object%5Bproperty%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Greeter%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20greeting%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20constructor(message%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.greeting%20%3D%20message%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20greet()%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22Hello%2C%20%22%20%2B%20this.greeting%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20static%20warm_greeter()%3A%20Greeter%20%7B%20return%20new%20Greeter(%27good%20o%5C%27%20fellow%27)%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20greeterBuilder%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20Greeter%20%3D%20getProp(Greeter%2C%20%27warm_greeter%27)%3B%20%2F%2F%20ok%0D%0Aalert(greeterBuilder().greet())%3B%20%2F%2F%20ok%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20greeterBuilderName%3A%20keyof%20Greeter%20%3D%20%27warm_greeter%27%3B%20%2F%2F%20does%20not%20build%20%3A(%0D%0AgreeterBuilder%20%3D%20getProp(Greeter%2C%20greeterBuilderName)%3B%20%2F%2F%20does%20not%20build%20%3A(%0D%0Aalert(greeterBuilder().greet())%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A), I am not able to type properly the `greeterBuilderName` variable so that it can be passed to getProp utility... `keyof Greeter` is actually the list of props/methods on *instances* of Greeter, how can I specify that I want props of the Greeter func itself (`prototype`, `warm_greeter`, ... ) ?

In other words, what is the proper type for `greeterBuilderName` ?

Thanks !

```
function getProp<T, K extends keyof T>(object: T, property: K): T[K] {
    return object[property];
}

class Greeter {
    private greeting: string;
    public constructor(message: string) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    public greet(): string {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    }
    public static warm_greeter(): Greeter { return new Greeter('good o\' fellow'); }
}

let greeterBuilder: () => Greeter = getProp(Greeter, 'warm_greeter'); // ok
alert(greeterBuilder().greet()); // ok

const greeterBuilderName: keyof Greeter = 'warm_greeter'; // does not build :(
greeterBuilder = getProp(Greeter, greeterBuilderName); // does not build :(
alert(greeterBuilder().greet());
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think you want to get the keys of the Greeter class itself, so

```
const greeterBuilderName: keyof typeof Greeter = 'warm_greeter';
```