# Is it possible to map properties name of an object as an array?

Tags: typescript

I'd like to do a type to record the name of the properties of an object (if I pass the static reference, should return only static properties) as an array. For example

```js
class C1 {

    p1 = 1;

    p2 = 2;

    static sp1 = 1;

    static sp2 = 2;

    m1() {

    }

    m2() {

    }

    static sm1() {

    }

    static sm2(): "hello" {
        return "hello";
    }

}


type NameOfProperties<T> = ...

type test = NameOfProperties<C1> //=> the result should be ["p1", "p2", "m1", "m2"]

type staticTest = NameOfProperties<typeof C1> //=> the result should be ["prototype", "sp1", "sp2", "sm1", "sm2"]
```

I'd like to know objectively, if is it possible to do that?

Comment: What you are looking for is `keyof`

Comment: Deleted 1 comment where I said `prototype` wouldn't be one of the keys. I just checked and `prototype` is one of the keys when doing `keyof typeof MyClass`

Comment: @ken-white Are you sure that edit was correct? To mee it seems like he wanted to ask about a TypeScript type, not a normal JavaScript array.

Comment: @zoran404: Yes, I'm sure that removing the redundant tag *Typescript* from the title was correct, because the actual *typescript* tag in the lower left corner of the question is all that is needed. Repeating tag information in the title when it is not absolutely necessary (as when asking about a specific version where a tag is not yet available) is simply useless noise.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [keyof for static properties of TypeScript classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42095669/keyof-for-static-properties-of-typescript-classes)

Comment: @KenWhite In that case I think the title should have been edited more to indicate that they are asking about types

Comment: @zoran404: Feel free to make that edit if you like. Remember that doing so will put it into the reopen queue.

Comment: @zoran404 no, I don't want the union of properties name, but an array. Unfortunately that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused, are you looking for a regular javascript array or for types for typescript?

Comment: @zoran404 types for typescript. An real array I capture with `Reflect.ownKeys` from JS, for example.

Comment: If you are looking for types, then my original answer is still what you want, you get it using `keyof`

Comment: @zoran404 I want a tuple kind not a union.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't get such a tuple from TS. TS doesn't track order of properties (e.g., `{a: string, b: number}` is the same type as `{b: number, a: string}`) and [trying to tease this info out of TS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55127004/2887218) is one of those Very Bad Ideas that will probably make things worse for you, not better. Why do you care about the exact order and length of this array? Maybe we can think of some other approach that will work for you.

Comment: @jcalz hello. The order doesn't is important, just all names in the list of properties.

Comment: If the order isn't important why do you want a tuple? What, specifically, is wrong with `Array<keyof typeof C1>`?

Comment: @jcalz I'll write an example.

Comment: @jcalz [this](https://tsplay.dev/mALqvN) is the example.

Comment: So then this question looks like a dupe of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52856496/2887218) where you can assert like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mpzdgw) shows, keeping in mind that it's technically possible for you to get keys at runtime that the compiler doesn't know about. Does that address the question fully or am I missing something?

Comment: @jcalz this question can looks like a dupe for you, but for me, no. There is a definitive list of property names referring to an object, I mean, this list is not random (although it is not enumerated with numerical indices), so if I tried to execute C1['anAnyProperty'], in this case it would be returned an `undefined`, right?! Whereas if I executed `C1['sm2']` it would return "hello", right?! When I place the mouse over the variable that was of the type I was looking for, the TS should show an `array` with all the property names.

Comment: The other question goes into detail about that and links to the sources. TS doesn't have so-called "exact types" so it can't be sure that an object doesn't have extra properties it doesn't know about. I'm not sure why you don't think it's a duplicate; surely the people in the other question also have objects whose property names are "definitive" and are unhappy that TypeScript doesn't recognize this. I'm not saying that the situation is ideal, but that's what it is. The closest you can get is `Array<keyof X>` here. Is there something you think I'm missing about this?

Comment: @jcalz sorry my english. I didn't know that "dupe" is a contracted form to "duplicate". And, no, you explained everything I needed to know. I am satisfied. Thanks for that.

Comment: Ohh, no problem. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

```
class C1 {
    p1 = 1;
    p2 = 2;

    static sp1 = 1;
    static sp2 = 2;

    m1() {}
    m2() {}

    static sm1() {}
    static sm2() {}
}

type NameOfProperties<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: K extends string | number | symbol ? K : never;
}[keyof T];

type Test = NameOfProperties<typeof C1>;
// Result: "p1" | "p2" | "prototype" | "sp1" | "sp2" | "m1" | "m2" | "sm1" | "sm2"
```

**However, note that:**
This includes instance properties, prototype properties, static properties, and methods. It does not filter out prototype properties (like "prototype"), and it includes method names.

Comment: That is not the result that the question asked for, in his example the result should only contain static properties and we already have an instruction for that, it is `keyof typeof C1`

Comment: In the `Result: ...` you show that `type Test` would have both static and instance properties, but actually it only has static properties, which is actually what the question asked for

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Kyle, but that isn't what I want. I want to transform the properties name as elements of an array.